# How to calculate a Directory size in ADLS using PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to calculate a directory(e.g- XYZ) size which contains sub folders and sub files.
I want total size of all the files and everything inside XYZ.

I could find out all the folders inside a particular path. But I want size of all together.
Also I see

`display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/datalake/.../XYZ/.../abc.parquet"))`

gives me data size of abc file.
But I want complete size of XYZ.

Comment: du -h wont work ?

Comment: can you please be more clear about your answer ?

Comment: du -h directorypath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dbutils.fs.ls` doesn't have a recurse functionality like `cp`, `mv` or `rm`. Thus, you need to iterate yourself. Here is a snippet that will do the task for you. Run the code from a Databricks Notebook.

```
from dbutils import FileInfo
from typing import List

root_path = "/mnt/datalake/.../XYZ"

def discover_size(path: str, verbose: bool = True):
  def loop_path(paths: List[FileInfo], accum_size: float):
    if not paths:
      return accum_size
    else:
      head, tail = paths[0], paths[1:]
      if head.size > 0:
        if verbose:
          print(f"{head.path}: {head.size / 1e6} MB")
        accum_size += head.size / 1e6
        return loop_path(tail, accum_size)
      else:
        extended_tail = dbutils.fs.ls(head.path) + tail
        return loop_path(extended_tail, accum_size)

  return loop_path(dbutils.fs.ls(path), 0.0)

discover_size(root_path, verbose=True)  # Total size in megabytes at the end
```

If the location is mounted in the dbfs. Then you could use the `du -h` approach (have not test it). If you are in the Notebook, create a new cell with:

```
%sh
du -h /mnt/datalake/.../XYZ
```

Comment: Any idea why this solution doesn't work with bigger size of directory ?

Comment: First I see OOM Issue and added sys.setrecursionlimit(2000). Now, 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'

Comment: The path must be very deep, you probably have many "subdirectories" until files are reached. Try increasing the 2k to something big like 500k. I'll try to pick this up later

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbutils'`

Answer (score 2):

The @Emer answer is good, but can hit a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` really quickly, because it does a recursion for each files (if you have X files you will have X imbricated recursions).

Here is the same thing with recursion only for folders:

```
%python
from dbutils import FileInfo
from typing import List

def discover_size2(path: str, verbose: bool = True):
  def loop_path(path: str):
    accum_size = 0.0
    path_list = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    if path_list:
      for path_object in path_list:
        if path_object.size > 0:
          if verbose:
            print(f"{path_object.path}: {path_object.size / 1e6} MB")
          accum_size += path_object.size / 1e6
        else:
          # Folder: recursive discovery
          accum_size += loop_path(path_object.path)
    return accum_size

  return loop_path(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still hitting recursion limits with @robin loche's approach, here is a purely iterative answer:

```
# from dbutils import FileInfo # Not required in databricks
# from dbruntime.dbutils import FileInfo # may work for some people

def get_size_of_path(path):
    return sum([file.size for file in get_all_files_in_path(path)])

def get_all_files_in_path(path, verbose=False):
    nodes_new = []

    nodes_new = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    files = []

    while len(nodes_new) > 0:
        current_nodes = nodes_new
        nodes_new = []
        for node in current_nodes:
            if verbose:
                print(f"Processing {node.path}")
            children = dbutils.fs.ls(node.path)
            for child in children:
                if child.size == 0 and child.path != node.path:
                    nodes_new.append(child)
                elif child.path != node.path:
                    files.append(child)
    return files

path = "s3://some/path/"

print(f"Size of {path} in gb: {get_size_of_path(path) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024}")
```

Comment: See @shizzhan;s answer for the reasoning behind the `from dbruntime.dbutils` line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dbutils ls command, get the list of files in a dataframe and query by using aggregate function SUM() on size column:

```
val fsds = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/datalake/.../XYZ/.../abc.parquet").toDF

fsds.createOrReplaceTempView("filesList")

display(spark.sql("select COUNT(name) as NoOfRows, SUM(size) as sizeInBytes from fileListPROD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Love the [answer by Emer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313616/)!

Small addition:

If you met

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbutils'"

try this `from dbruntime.dbutils` instead of `from dbutils`. It works for me!

-- Shizheng