# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbutils'

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to run the accepted answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312078/how-to-calculate-a-directory-size-in-adls-using-pyspark) on a Azure Databricks Notebook which yields the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbutils'`

After looking up the error I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546680/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyspark-dbutils), however, I'm unable to determine whether the errors are similar. The post isn't very helpful either.

Running `dbutils.fs.ls(path)` works but Importing the module using

`from dbutils import FileInfo` yields the above error.

I'm also unable to deduce if this is an issue with different module names overlapping.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do `type(dbutils)` you can find that it's `dbruntime.dbutils.DBUtils`, not `dbutils.something`.  Similarly, if you do `type(dbutils.fs.ls("/")[0])`, then you get `dbruntime.dbutils.FileInfo` that could be imported as:

```py
from dbruntime.dbutils import FileInfo
```

But real question - why do you need to import `FileInfo`?

Comment: Thanks it worked like a Charm! FileInfo was mentioned in the accepted answer in the post I was referring to

Comment: please note that this package name could depend on the DBR version as it's internal detail and can change at any time